# Compare multiple variables

Tags: variables, lua, compare

I have a several number of variables with 2 arguments, I would like to compare a value with them, and modify the ones who are equal all that in one time, without writing every possibility of `If mynumber == x then x = ("NewValue") elseif mynumber == y then .......` because I have A LOT of variables to check.
Example:

```
x = 5 and ("Five")

y = 2 and ("Two")

z = 10 and ("Ten")

mynumber = io.read()
```

*Now check within all variables if one equals to mynumber, and change that(these) variable(s) to XXX*

So, do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mean to, I'm new on this site. I didn't even see the changes. I was just correcting some mistakes, why do you not put a comment ?

Comment: Oh, I think you were editing while I was, so yours overwrote mine.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I was just adding a variable example. Thanks for making this post more readable (do we say that? I'm swiss, english isn't my first language)

Comment: Yes, that's a common phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Use a table:

```
local lookup = {
    foo = "bar",
    bar = "baz",
    baz = "foo",
    ["some thing"] = "other thing",
}

local x = "foo"
x = lookup[x]
```

If you're trying to convert words for numbers into numbers themselves:

```
local lookup = {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    -- Continue on for however long you need to
}

local x = "Two"
print(lookup[x]) -- Prints 2

local y = 3
print(lookup[y]) -- Prints nil, the number 3 isn't in the table

-- Better:
print(lookup[x] or x) -- Prints 2, as there was a truthy entry in lookup for x
print(lookup[y] or y) -- Prints 3; there wasn't a truthy entry in lookup for y, but y is truthy so that's used.
```

This is a bit more practical than a giant if-else chain, but can still be cumbersome for larger numbers. If you need to support those, you may need to split up the word for each digit (ex. `"Thirty Two"` to `{"Thirty", "Two"}`).

Comment: Okay I've tried this way, but still I don't know/understand how to change the variables that are equals to x.